# Multiple select control for web

Tags: javascript, user-controls, listbox

We need a special user control for our web application.

It should ideally look and work exactly like typical `<select>` element but with additional feature that would allow user to select multiple choices.

I imagine it like drop-down list of items with checkboxes. User can either select one and only item by clicking it (just like normal selectbox) or click checkboxes, thus selecting more options.

Something quite similar are **Move to** and **Labels** buttons in Gmail interface.

Can you recommend such product? Should we develop our own solution? Can you recommend resources or how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this J-Query based solution ([jQuery Dropdown Check List](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html) by Adrian Tosca) is a little bit more robust.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add the `multiple` attribute to your `select` tag e.g.:

```
<select multiple name="myselect">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Good point. It however is not good enough: a) It does not look as selectbox at all; b) It is not very intuitive; Our users are generally not technically savvy and this control is not very good display of great user interface.

Answer (score 1):

HTML's [`<select>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-SELECT) already provides this:

> **multiple [CI]**
>
> If set, this boolean attribute allows multiple selections. If not set, the SELECT element only permits single selections.